# Migrate 365 tenant to new tenant with on-premise sync

Tags: synchronization, office365, office365-apps

We are currently looking at solutions for migrating to a new tenant. We have a 365 tenant with multiple domains. All accounts on this tenant are synced from the current Active Directory.

1 company is going independent, and are going to use their own tenant of Office 365. They will also use set up their own infrastructure (DC).
We will migrate the domain of their company, as well as the users. In their future infrastructure, they want to sync 365 with their own Active Directory again.

What is the best way to accomplish this? 
In short: We want to migrate AD-Synced users, to a new tenant which will also use AD-sync.

If we migrate the users now, and use AD-sync after we recreated them on their new DC, they will have duplicate accounts in O365?

Answer (score 0):

The best way to migrate a company on premise AD into Azure AD which is the core of o365 authentication is to use Azure connect tool. Here is a detailed step by step walkthrough on how to do implement this.

https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/active-directory-aadconnect/

Hope this helps.